# Linking collections in GraphQL resolver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, graphql, apollo

I am trying to join two collections in GraphQL query.

My data is as follows:
Cruises:

```
[
  {
    "cruiseID" : "00001",
    "title" : "title 1",
    "description" : "desc 1",
    "startDate" : 20150820,
    "endDate" : 20150827,
    "numDays" : 8,
    "startPort" : "Juneau, Alaska",
    "roomTypes" : [
      {"roomID" : "IPD"},
      {"roomID" : "SDS"}
    ]
  }, {
    "cruiseID" : "00002",
    "title" : "title 1",
    "description" : "desc 2",
    "startDate" : 20150710,
    "endDate" : 20150724,
    "numDays" : 14,
    "startPort" : "San Diego",
    "roomTypes" : [
      {"roomID" : "IPD"},
      {"roomID" : "SJS"},
      {"roomID" : "SDS"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Rooms:

```
[
  {
    "roomID": "IPD",
    "roomDetails": {
        "roomType": "IPD aaaaa",
        "title": "aaaa",
        "description": "ddddd",
        "maxOccupants": 2
    },
    "capacity": [
      {"cruiseID": "00001", "total": 21, "available": 20},
      {"cruiseID": "00002", "total": 31, "available": 30}
    ]
  },
  {
    "roomID": "SJS",
    "roomDetails": {
        "roomType": "SJS aaaa",
        "title": "aaaaa",
        "description": "aaaaa",
        "maxOccupants": 4
    },
    "capacity": [
      {"cruiseID": "00001", "available": 27},
      {"cruiseID": "00002", "available": 27}
    ]
  },
  {
    "roomID": "SDS",
    "roomDetails": {
        "roomType": "SDS aaa",
        "title": "sssss",
        "description": "sssssss",
        "maxOccupants": 4
    },
    "capacity": [
      {"cruiseID": "00001", "available": 20},
      {"cruiseID": "00002", "available": 20}
    ]
  }
]
```

My GraphQL schema:

```
type Query {
  Cruises: [Cruise]
}

type RoomDetails {
  roomType: String
  title: String
  description: String
  maxOccupants: Int
}

type Capacity {
  cruiseID: String
  total: Int
  available: Int
}

type Room {
  roomID: String
  roomDetails: RoomDetails
  capacity: [Capacity]
}

type Cruise {
  _id: ID
  cruiseID: String
  title: String
  description: String
  startDate: Int
  endDate: Int
  numDays: Int
  startPort: String
  roomTypes: [Room]
}
```

My GraphQL resolver where I try to print details for roomTypes by reading them from rooms collection:

```
const Query = {
  Cruises: async () => {
    data = await db.collection('cruises').find().toArray().then(res => { return res });
    return data
  }
}

const Cruise = {
  roomTypes: async (root) => {
    data = await db.collection('rooms').find({'roomID': 'SDS'}).toArray().then(res => { return res });
    // prints OK
    logger.debug(`root.roomTypes.roomID': ${JSON.stringify(root.roomTypes[1].roomID)}`);
    // undefined
    logger.debug(`root.roomTypes.roomID': ${JSON.stringify(root.roomTypes.roomID)}`);
    // prints OK
    logger.debug(`root.startPort': ${root.startPort}`);
    return data
  }
}

module.exports = {
  Query,
  Cruise
}
```

I can't find a proper join between Cruises and Rooms.
Hardcoded {'roomID': 'SDS'} works OK i.e. shows proper output.
However, I can't find a way to properly pass roomID from Cruises to the find filter. Any hints?

UPDATE:
When I implement the resolver life this:

```
const Cruise = {
  roomTypes: async (root) => {
    data = await db.collection('rooms').find({'capacity.cruiseID': root.cruiseID}).toArray().then(res => { return res })
    //data = await db.collection('rooms').find().toArray().then(res => { return res })

    return data
  }
}
```

I get the data back (roomTypes fully resolved) but, it doesn't do any filtering/joining actually.
Here's what I get (edited with some rubbish data so it's shorter):

```
    "data": {
        "Cruises": [
            {
                "cruiseID": "00001",
                "title": "and",
                "startDate": 20150820,
                "endDate": 20150827,
                "numDays": 8,
                "startPort": "Juneau, Alaska",
                "roomTypes": [
                    {
                        "roomID": "IPD",
                        "roomDetails": {
                            "roomType": "asd",
                            "title": "and",
                            "description": "asdr",
                            "maxOccupants": 2
                        },
                        "capacity": [
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00001",
                                "total": 21,
                                "available": 20
                            },
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00002",
                                "total": 31,
                                "available": 30
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "roomID": "OPD",
                        "roomDetails": {
                            "roomType": "ad",
                            "title": "and",
                            "description": "asdr",
                            "maxOccupants": 2
                        },
                        "capacity": [
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00001",
                                "total": null,
                                "available": 30
                            },
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00002",
                                "total": null,
                                "available": 30
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "roomID": "SDD",
                        "roomDetails": {
                            "roomType": "asd",
                            "title": "and",
                            "description": "and",
                            "maxOccupants": 2
                        },
                        "capacity": [
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00001",
                                "total": null,
                                "available": 25
                            },
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00002",
                                "total": null,
                                "available": 25
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "roomID": "SD2",
                        "roomDetails": {
                            "roomType": "asd",
                            "title": "and",
                            "description": "Fast",
                            "maxOccupants": 4
                        },
                        "capacity": [
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00001",
                                "total": null,
                                "available": 22
                            },
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00002",
                                "total": null,
                                "available": 22
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "roomID": "SJS",
                        "roomDetails": {
                            "roomType": "asd",
                            "title": "and",
                            "description": "Tasdr",
                            "maxOccupants": 4
                        },
                        "capacity": [
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00001",
                                "total": null,
                                "available": 27
                            },
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00002",
                                "total": null,
                                "available": 27
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "roomID": "SDS",
                        "roomDetails": {
                            "roomType": "asd",
                            "title": "and",
                            "description": "Tase",
                            "maxOccupants": 4
                        },
                        "capacity": [
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00001",
                                "total": null,
                                "available": 20
                            },
                            {
                                "cruiseID": "00002",
                                "total": null,
                                "available": 20
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
```

instead of only having 2 room types (IPD, SDS) listed for cruiseID 00001 as per the entries in Cruises collection.

Comment: `Cruise.roomTypes` (subfield) resolver then 'cruises' collection (not 'rooms') find by root.id (cruise) "cruiseID" : root.id ... already an array ... then in loop find rooms by type where capacity entry matches cruiseid

Comment: Thanks for commenting. However, I don't understand your comment. Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: `Resolver chains` Try here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#resolver-chains. Follow the code example (Otherwise it is a little hard to catch the idea). `Library` & `Books`  (In your case `Cruise` & `Rooms`)

Comment: `Cruise = {
  roomTypes` .... `roomTypes` already resolved (partialy - only roomId prop from cruises entries - overwriting, maybe you wanted some 'rooms' prop?) in Query.Cruises (returned objects)? console.log(data)? ... you need to resolve 'missing' Room type properties (roomDetails, capacity) ... Room.roomDetails resolver will get room as parent with roomID (but apollo cache needs 'id'/'_id' unique field for each types - roomdetails)

Comment: Please see my update in the question. I am getting the roomTypes resolved. I just can't get the proper data in it.

Comment: Maybe also add one playground `query data` to your Q.

Comment: @EzraSiton- thanks - going through this again now - it's confusing

Comment: `console.log(root.roomTypes)` at the begining of roomTypes resolver - use this array to find related values/filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally did it. It's not the cleanest code/solution but it does the job.

```
const Cruise = {
  roomTypes: async (root) => {
    let rooms = root.roomTypes;
    allRooms = await db.collection('rooms').find().toArray().then(res => { return res });
    rooms.forEach(room => {
      let currentRoomID = room.roomID;
      currentRoom = allRooms.filter(function(r) {
        return r.roomID === currentRoomID;
      });
      currentRoomCapacity = currentRoom[0].capacity.filter(function(c) {
        return c.cruiseID === root.cruiseID;
      });
      room.roomDetails = currentRoom[0].roomDetails
      room.capacity = currentRoomCapacity
    });
    return rooms;
  }
}
```